Wrong time in Docker Desktop(MacOs)
Following shows one hour earlier than host.
Note the time difference(20:08:42 vs 21:08:44):
docker run -it alpine date
Mon Dec  9 20:08:42 UTC 2024

Also tried:
docker run -it -e TZ=Europe/Berlin alpine date

Date on host(Host is also in Europe/Berlin timezone):
Mon Dec  9 21:08:44 CET 2024

Same for any container running in Docker.
Environment:
docker version
Client:
 Version:           27.3.1
 API version:       1.47
 Go version:        go1.22.7
 Git commit:        ce12230
 Built:             Fri Sep 20 11:38:18 2024
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.36.0 (175267)
 Engine:
  Version:          27.3.1
  API version:      1.47 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.22.7
  Git commit:       41ca978
  Built:            Fri Sep 20 11:41:19 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.21
  GitCommit:        472731909fa34bd7bc9c087e4c27943f9835f111
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.13
  GitCommit:        v1.1.13-0-g58aa920
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0


The time reported looks correct (in the specified/default UTC timezone) given that you are at GMT+1. The base alpine image is minimal and does not include timezone data so setting TZ will not help - see this answer.
